# Native windows cmd program to download a file

Tags: windows, batch

I'm struggling with the windows commandline for years. Is it possible to download a file over http(/https) with the programs that are shipped with windows by default?

I know that I can download or program additional software and add it to the %PATH% to do the job but I'm looking for a solution that works out of the box.

This program should be available on the home version of windows.

Comment: Well, there is no such program other than Internet Explorer (and that's not quite suitable). What's wrong with using wget from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ for example?

Comment: I like it to use things I can find on any computer, without downloading things that should already be there (also it's pretty ironic that I would have to download a program if I want to be able to download things).

Comment: I don't know every stackexchange board yet and I thought batch would be a stackoverflow question. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: What versions of Windows do you have in mind? Vista, 7 or also XP?

Comment: bitsadmin.exe may be an option, depending on your version of Windows.  I think it works for generic http downloads, i.e., even if the server doesn't support BITS, although I'm not certain.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows 7 and above:

open powershell.exe and type:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png","C:\g.png")
```

Comment: Would this not also work in Windows XP and Vista, provided Powershell was installed?

Comment: Yes, it should work in XP and Vista but he didn't want to install anything. I was more concerned that PowerShell is not part of the Windows 7 Home Edition, but it seems it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a batch file to open iexplore.exe and load an URL, if the URL went straight to the download page. I don't think this is the best option (agree wget or curl would work more the way you seem to be looking for) but if you want to use OEM-only tools this is an option.

See [Internet Explorer Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728(v=vs.85).aspx)

> IE - Open website in multiple tabs - possible with .js file
>
> Sometime back I wanted to open multiple websites in different tabs. I
>   tried something like below
>
> ```
> iexplore "microsoft.com" "msn.com" "whatever.com"
> ```
>
> As you might have tried, that didnt work as expected. I found a .js
>   script to do that for me. Here it is below. Have the script in a .js
>   file. I couldnt locate where I found it from. But I am guessing that
>   it was from Eric Lippert blog.
>
> ```
> var navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
> var oIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
> oIE.Navigate2("http://blogs.msdn.com");
> oIE.Navigate2("http://blogs.msdn.com/tonyschr", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
> oIE.Navigate2("http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
> oIE.Navigate2("http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert", navOpenInBackgroundTab);
> oIE.Visible = true;
> ```
>
> Save the above code in launchie.js. Double click. There you go.

Comment: Please learn how to format posts. Check their preview so that they really look like intended. You need to indent code by 4 spaces or by pressing `Ctrl-K` on the selected code. You also should quote anything you didn't write yourself by using the blockquote feature. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I've obviously got a lot to learn about posting on here. Thanks for the information. I will educate myself before posting further.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Windows-native" standalone `.exe` program that simply downloads a file via HTTP.

Internet Explorer exposes much of its functionality via COM components/objects, including HTTP/HTTPS dowloading, but this requires at least some scripting to use.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, there is not. The best idea is to have a windows version of Wget on a USB stick, can do anything, but quite difficult to understand all its possible options.

Try the binaries provides by the gnuwin32 project:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Although they seem to be a bit late on gnu releases.